# how select from the database where the colum has the highest value in a table in sql

Tags: php, sql

i have this table that has some data, but i want to get the row where a paticular coluom `votecount` has the highest value:

| id | votecount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 13 |

i tried this sql statement:

```
$selectr = "SELECT *, MAX(`votecount`) from `audio`"; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($selectr);
$stmt->execute([]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $userid = $row["id"];
    $votecount = $row["votecount"];
    echo $userid;
    echo $votecount;
}
```

but it echos out 10 which means it got the first item in the table and the value is 0, which is wrong, its not getting the highest column

so how do i fix this

Comment: You should be able to use `order by` and `limit` to acheive this easily - `select * from audio order by votecount desc limit 1`

Comment: this is the most brilliant idea i have gotten, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$selectr = "SELECT * from `audio` where `votecount` = ( SELECT MAX(`votecount`) from `audio`)"; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($selectr);
$stmt->execute([]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $userid = $row["id"];
    $votecount = $row["votecount"];
    echo $userid;
    echo $votecount;
}
```

Comment: this gives me the error: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function in C:\xampp\htdocs\oohdio\php\fromToptoPromoted.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\oohdio\php\fromToptoPromoted.php(5): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\oohdio\php\fromToptoPromoted.php on line 5`

Comment: Please try using HAVING instead of WHERE

Answer (score -2):

Try correct: $userid = $row["**userId**"]; to $userid = $row["**id**"];

Comment: i changed it and now i find out it selects the first item in the database